# Git - fatal: Could not get current working directory?

Tags: linux, git, bash, unix, gitlab

When I `git clone` from a repo, I get,

`fatal: Could not get current working directory: No such file or directory`

What do I do? I have checked the server and found that `.git` file exists. The server is running a Gitlab instance. I have configured `ssh` properly with the keys, and I've been committing & cloning for a while now without any error, and this happens all of a sudden.

FWIW, I'm doing the `git clone` in a bash script.

---

**Update**

This is my bash script,

```
for repo in $repos
do
   git clone $repo /tmp/tmpdir/
   # do stuff with /tmp/tmpdir/
   rm -rf /tmp/tmpdir/
done
```

for the first `repo` it's fine, but when the `for` gets into the second `repo` it fails and gives the above `fatal` error.

Comment: Does the bash script delete any directories? It sounds like you've deleted the working directory.

Comment: Working directory is wherever the script is run from, unless that script changes directory. How are you calling the script?

Comment: Presumably somewhere in your `do stuff` you `cd` into `/tmp/tmpdir/`? If so, add `cd /tmp/` before your `rm` line.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey Ridiculously awesome! I can't believe I was missing this.

Comment: I'll add that as an answer.

Comment: @DaveMorrissey Please do, will accept. :) Silly me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that somewhere in your `do stuff` section you change directory into `/tmp/tmpdir/` so that in the next loop, the current working directory no longer exists. The fix is to change directory to `/tmp/` (or anywhere really) before removing the `/tmp/tmdir/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this was caused by issuing a "git clone" from a subdirectory of an already existing git repo.  I had to cd outside of the existing repo before I could clone the new repo.