# "Could not get current working directory" error on git clone

Tags: git, powershell, git-clone, azure-devops

I try to clone a Git repository hosted on a VSTS instance in a PowerShell script to a network share:

```
git clone https://user:password@mycompany.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/MyProject/_git/MyRepository \\MyServer\MyBackupDirectory\MyRepository --mirror
```

While this works fine run from my local machine it fails while run on another machine (VSTS build agent) with the following error:

```
fatal: Could not get current working directory: No such file or directory
```

The same error is thrown if I run the above command directly in PowerShell. I don't see how this could be related to the working directory. I suspect that it has something to do with permissions on the target file share, but the user has full control on the target path and with the same user I can manually create / delete folders in the target path.

Opposite to [Git - fatal: Could not get current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138228/git-fatal-could-not-get-current-working-directory) I also don't change working directory or delete directories.

**Update:** 
If I don't clone with `--mirror` an empty directory is created on the target file share and I get the following errors:

```
fatal: Could not get current working directory: No such file or directory
Deletion of directory ´\\MyServer\MyBackupDirectory\MyRepository´ failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

Comment: How do you run it from your local machine? Does it also fail when you run the command directly in PowerShell on the local machine?

Comment: On my local workstation it works while running directly from PowerShell. On the build agent (with a different user) it fails with the error above either run as a VSTS build or directly in PowerShell.

Comment: Does the user on build agent have enough permission to access to the network folder?

Comment: Yes, I can access the newtwork folder from the build agent with the user under which the vsts agent runs, create folders, delete folders, etc (User has Full Control access)